# Searchable spinner making app crash

Tags: android, spinner

I am having trouble with using a searchable spinner. I have followed a tutorial ([this one](https://www.mytrendin.com/implement-search-functionality-android-spinner/)) to get a searchable spinner working in my app. Currently I have a normal spinner which is populated by items from a csv file, and you can duplicate those spinners by pressing the FAB button I have implemented. But when I try changing 'Spinner' widget to 'SearchableSpinner' in my code, my app crashes when I go to duplicate a spinner.  I have put asterisks in my code to show where I've got my spinner code.

Create.java code:

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {



    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    private ArrayList<Spinner> mSpinners;
    Button buttontest;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();

        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);

        //mLinearLayout.addView(makeSpinner());    // First spinner



        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = //this code is for the FAB, which adds more slots
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Handle the click.
                SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner); //Add another spinner


                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)spinner.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setMargins( 5,  130,  10,  0);
                layoutParams.height = 80;//pixels
                layoutParams.width = 240;//pixels
                spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


                //Add a new button
                AppCompatButton newButton = makeButton();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newButton);      // Add another button

                //Add a new checkbox
                CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

                EditText newEdittext = makeEdittext();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newEdittext);
            }
        });


    }


    //DUPLICATING ITEMS WHEN + IS PRESSED

    private CheckBox makeCheckbox() {
        //Create new Checkbox
        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return checkbox;
    }


    private EditText makeEdittext() {
        //Create new eddittext
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); //sets it to a numeric edittext instead of textboard

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return editText;


    }


    private AppCompatButton makeButton() {
        //Create new Button
        AppCompatButton button = new AppCompatButton(this);


        // code for deleting button //
        buttontest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontest);
        buttontest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttontest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                makeCheckbox().setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }); //end






        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


        return button;
    }

    **private Spinner makeSpinner() {**
        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String> itemList = csvFile.read();

        //Create new spinner
        **SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);





        //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
        mSpinners.add(spinner);
        return spinner;
    }



    //csv file code
    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

> 08-09 17:10:42.500 18803-18803/com.app.supermarketaislefinder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
>           at com.app.supermarketaislefinder.create.makeSpinner(create.java:171)
>           at com.app.supermarketaislefinder.create.access$000(create.java:37)
>           at com.app.supermarketaislefinder.create$1.onClick(create.java:74)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Where is your Crash log?

Comment: I have edited in log.

Comment: It is quite obvious that you can't cast a `Spinner` that you create to `SearchableSpinner`. You need to create `SearchableSpinner` (`SearchableSpinner spinner = new SearchableSpinner(...)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are referring `SearchableSpinner` example, you need to have list of `SearchableSpinner` like below. **SearchableSpinner is a customized Spinner**.

```
private ArrayList<SearchableSpinner> mSpinners;
```

Remove below line of code and initialize your `SearchableSpinner` properly, see [SearchableSpinner](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/blob/master/searchablespinnerlibrary/src/main/java/com/toptoche/searchablespinnerlibrary/SearchableSpinner.java)

```
// SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);
    SearchableSpinner spinner = new SearchableSpinner(this);
    mSpinners.add(spinner);
```

Comment: Sometimes happen because of typo, Thank you for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mSpinners` `ArrayList` is of `Spinner` widget not the List of `SearchableSpinner` `widget`

Use This

```
private ArrayList<SearchableSpinner> mSpinners;
```

Instead of this

```
private ArrayList<Spinner> mSpinners;
```

**EDIT**

You need to return the  `widget` of `SearchableSpinner` in your `makeSpinner()` method

```
private SearchableSpinner makeSpinner() {**
        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String> itemList = csvFile.read();

        //Create new spinner
        **SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) new SearchableSpinner(this);

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);





        //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
        mSpinners.add(spinner);
        return spinner;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for that . I still seem to be getting the same log cat error?

Comment: may be problem is with his `makeSpinner()` returning Spinner

Comment: this is not the main problem here. It will crash after applying your changes

Comment: whenever I still press the floating action button it still crashes with same log

Comment: @Redman yes  he needs to return `SearchableSpinner` instead of `spinner`

Comment: @crazyCoderN share that new crash log with question